# User submitted posts in wordpress 3.0

Tags: php, wordpress, plugins

I am in the middle of building a site with user submitted posts that let the user upload a zip file along with images. At the moment I am using TDO-Miniforms and wordpress 2.9.2, but TDO-miniforms has stopped development and is broken with wordpress 3.0 that just came out. I would like to update the site to 3.0 but I don't know of any alternatives to TDO-miniforms that let logged in users submit posts with attachments and images.

Any alternatives?

Comment: I suggest asking this on superuser.com

Comment: This Q belongs here - SuperUser explicitly says it is NOT about `websites or web services like Facebook, Twitter, and WordPress`

Answer (score 0):

I would assume that with the popularity of TDO, *someone* may take it upon themselves to either help out or take on the project to bring up to 3.0.

What I would suggest to encourage this progression is;

1. Contacting the developer(s) to show your support
2. Donate to the project
3. Rallying fellow developers on WordPress IRC and the forums to take on the project